# Original Text Sources for 2 Aristotle ideas - 1/ nous on nous , 2/ sprial of knowledge - which texts did Aristotle first mention these in?

Tags: ethics, history-of-philosophy, aristotle, knowledge, ancient-philosophy

I am trying to track down the first mention original sources of some ideas of Aristotle in philosophy that some philosophy professors made in some university lectures.

The first idea is 
1/ Nous on Nous, (or Intellect on Intellect) - what was first text that Aristotle made mention of this idea?
2/ spiral of knowledge - again what was first text?

thanks 
Anti-Tao

Comment: *Nous* is discussed in Ch.3 of *De Anima*... But I have difficulty to understand what do you mean with "Intellect on Intellect".

Comment: "Spiral of knowledge" is some kind of metaphor or model that does not look likely to be find in Aristotle's texts. The question being rather vague, one thinks about some comment by Hegel, a huge fan of spirals ( and helix is the Greek word for spiral).

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness - I was just conveying my understanding and memory of what the philosophy professor's said